# Tag synonym suggestions

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I suggest the following synonyms:

[novelty](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novelty) → [novelties](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novelties)

[simul](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simul) → [simultaneous](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simultaneous)

Comment: Both suggestions seem reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have reworked the [novelty](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novelty) into [novelties](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novelties). Done and done, albeit a little late.